# When my asp.net button is clicked, my jQuery page functionaily breaks

Tags: jquery, asp.net, onclick, linkbutton

I have implemented the jQueryPagination plugin to allow easy paging of a repeater control.  This is working fine, however on this page I have a user control that allows the user to search for a ticket number.  When the button to search is clicked, the pagination goes away and I see all of the repeater information, as well as my returned search result.

When I click the link button my jQuery seems to be non-existant.

Code:

```
<div id="msgLinks" class="subtabs">
            <asp:TextBox runat="server"  ID="txtSearchTicket"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CausesValidation="false"
                onclick="lbSearch_Click" />
 </div>
```

jQuery (works on page load)

```
$('#tblRecAct').paginateTable({
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        Title: ".h1RecentActivity"
    });
    $('#tblMSG').paginateTable({
        rowsPerPage: 2,
        Title: ".h1SubmittedMessages",
        pager: ".pager2",
        pageNumbers: ".pageNumbers2"

    });
```

I have even tried calling

```
$(".subtabs a").click(function () {
        alert("Clicked");
        $('#tblRecAct').paginateTable({
            rowsPerPage: 5,
            Title: ".h1RecentActivity"
        });
    });
```

but it still does not work.  Any ideas?

**EDIT**
New Code per request:

Page -

```
public string _Js = "";
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                rptRecentMessages.DataSource = CMS.Model.Profile.RecentMessages(0, "");
                rptRecentMessages.DataBind();
                _Js = "CreatePaging();";
                LoadStatusMessages();
            }
        }
```

User Control (holds the search button) -

```
rptRecentActivity.DataSource = CMS.Model.Profile.RecentActivity(20);
rptRecentActivity.DataBind();
_Js = "CreatePaging();";
```

Search Button Click -

```
protected void lbSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string searchTerms = txtSearchTicket.Text;
            if (searchTerms == "")
                txtSearchTicket.Style.Add("border", "1px solid red");
            else
            {
                rptRecentMessages.DataSource = CMS.Model.Profile.RecentMessages(1, searchTerms);
                rptRecentMessages.DataBind();
                _Js = "CreatePaging();";
                LoadStatusMessages();
            }
        }
```

jQuery Code on the Page -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function CreatePaging(){
            $('#tblRecAct').paginateTable({
                rowsPerPage: 5,
                Title: ".h1RecentActivity"
            });
            $('#tblMSG').paginateTable({
                rowsPerPage: 2,
                Title: ".h1SubmittedMessages",
                pager: ".pager2",
                pageNumbers: ".pageNumbers2"

            });
        }

        $().ready(function(){
            <% =(this._Js) %>

        });

    });



</script>
```

When I am debugging and click on the search link now, I do not get a postback to a page_load and I am not sure why.

Comment: Paste the actual HTML that your ASP code generates

Comment: why would you use `onclick="..."` attribute when you using jquery ur defeating its soul purpose

Comment: I think it's because when you click the linkbutton, postback occurs which results in the current behavior. Try putting `return false;` below the last line of your code which is fired when clicking the linkbutton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the click to

```
$(".subtabs a").click(function () {
    alert("Clicked");
    $('#tblRecAct').paginateTable({
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        Title: ".h1RecentActivity"
    });
    return false;
});
```

adding the code `return false;` will prevent the link from clicking but will run your jQuery code.

**EDIT**

Put your jQUery code into a function so that you can easily call it from your c#

```
function CreatePaging(){
    $('#tblRecAct').paginateTable({
        rowsPerPage: 5,
        Title: ".h1RecentActivity"
    });
    $('#tblMSG').paginateTable({
        rowsPerPage: 2,
        Title: ".h1SubmittedMessages",
        pager: ".pager2",
        pageNumbers: ".pageNumbers2"

    });
}

$().ready(function(){
    <% =(this._Js) %>
});
```

Then in your code behind, have a public string variable called _Js and when you bind the Repeater, set `_Js = "CreatePaging();";`

Comment: That certainly fixed the issue of the pagination breaking, however now my c# code for the button click does not get called.

Comment: Ahh, ok well what you will need to do is output the jQuery again after postback. So even though it is running on the page, output it again after postback.

Comment: How would I force it to run again after postback?  If possible I would like to eliminate coding my jQuery in my C# but I can if needed, what do you suggest?

Comment: This seems to be throwing a ";" expected error in my Page reference (Page Title = "" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="" etc)  I can not get it to build doing this

Comment: I didn't post the exact code, just a rough example of what to do.

Comment: @Tim it was my fault I forgot to include something...however everytime I hit the search my pagination still goes away so this did not seem to fix the error

Comment: I think you will need to post a bit more of your code so we can see what is going wrong. html/jquery/c#